# Adding additional parameter to form submit

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, razor

I have a form declaration in my Razor view

```
<form method="post" action="/Lot/LotList?auctionEventId=@auctionEventId" id="filterForm">
```

(Incidentally, I chose to write it out like this rather than use `Html.BeginFrom` because I needed to give it an id and didn't know how to do that with `Html.BeginFrom` - but that is not the issue here)

Outside of this form I have a button which submits this form (there is also a submit button in the form)

```
<input type="button" onclick="$('#filterForm').submit();" value="Show all" />
```

Now, the issue is that if this button is used to submit the form I want the action in the form to change to

```
action="/Lot/LotList?auctionEventId=@auctionEventId&showAll=true"
```

How do I alter the action and pass this additional parameter?  Is there a totally better way of doing all this?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Appending query string parameters onto the form action, and trying to change that at runtime is tricky (but not impossible). Far easier is to use hidden fields:

```
<form method="post" action="/Lot/LotList" id="filterForm">
  <input type="hidden" name="auctionEventId" value="@auctionEventId" />
  ...
```

So now all you have to do is add another hidden field for "showAll"

```
<form method="post" action="/Lot/LotList" id="filterForm">
  <input type="hidden" name="auctionEventId" value="@auctionEventId" />
  <input type="hidden" name="showAll" value="false" id="showAllField" />
  ...
```

And just hook up a jquery event on your showAll button:

```
<input id="showAllButton" type="button"/>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#showAllButton').click(function(){
     $('#showAllField').val("true");
     $('#filterForm').submit();
});
```

Answer (score 9):

I know you said this is not the issue but you can add attributes to `Html.BeginForm` like this:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName","ControllerName", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "filterform" })){
```

Answer (score 8):

how about putting a hidden input

```
<form method="post" action="/Lot/LotList?auctionEventId=@auctionEventId" id="filterForm">

<input type="hidden" id="showAll" name="showAll" value=""/>
```

on your button

```
<input type="button" onclick="submitForm()" value="Show all" />
```

on your script somewhere

```
function submitForm(){
$('#showAll').val('true');
$('#filterForm').submit();

}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are within a form you can add the route to a button element. You can override the native action of the form by using formAction and formMethod. You can also have multiple buttons with other formActions and formMethods

```html
<form action="/somewhere" method="get">
    <input type="type" name="name" value=" " />


    <button formaction="/Lot/LotList?auctionEventId=@auctionEventId&showAll=true" formmethod="post">Show All</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello I found this to work very well

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName","ControllerName",  new { id = "filterform" },FormMethod.Post)){
```

I had tired to do the 'FormMethod.Post' before the param but it didn't work and never passed the value. Only through trial and error did I manage to solve it and figured out that it should be like the code I posted.

Hope that helps

Comment: This is exactly same solution gived for @yardpenalty in this question... Copy and paste? https://stackoverflow.com/a/20623003/4654957

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple submit buttons for the same form, and you need to pass a different parameter for each of them, you can use the asp-route attribute to accomplish this task.

```
 <input type="submit" value="Save"/>

 <input id="btnComplete" type="submit"
        asp-route-addNewOneAfterSave="@true"
        value="Save And Create New One">
```

Just remember to have your parameter in the OnPost method, for examples:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(bool? addNewOneAfterSave)
        {
             //Your code ....
        }
```

You can read more about the asp-route anchor tag helper from this [article.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-3.1)