# How to delete item from dropdown menu on change, php

Tags: php, mysql

I have select tag, and dropdown menu, I want to delete item, when it's selected, like, on change

Here is my code:

```
    $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'php_wood');
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts";
  $post = $db->query($sql);

    
  if(isset($_GET['postDelete'])){

      $delete = $_GET['postDelete'];
      
          $sql = "DELETE FROM posts WHERE id = `$delete`";

        mysqli_query($db, $sql);
         
        }
```

I don't know where  is mistake, here is my form

```
   <form action="delete.php" method="get">
    <select     id="" onchange="this.form.submit();" name="postDelete">
    <?php 
            if($post->num_rows > 0){
                while($row = $post->fetch_assoc()){
                    ?>
  <option  value="<?php echo $row['id']?>"><?php echo $row['title']?></option>


  <?php
                }
              }
  ?>
        <option value="">
        </option>
    </select>
    </form>
```

Comment: The code looks basically fine. But what debugging have you done?

Comment: the code is **vulnerable** to **sql injection** use nly **prepred statements with parameters-**

Comment: error is instead this signs `` on `$delete`, I should use '' '$delete'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding additional parameter to form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13162819/adding-additional-parameter-to-form-submit)